# How to Redirect ALL CATEGORY PAGES to Home page

Tags: .htaccess

This question is no where to be found.

I need a specific category to redirect **all pages on that category** to home page.

http://www.example.com/category/post1
http://www.example.com/category/and-so-on

How to redirect ALL pages on that specific category to home page? Any ideas?

Comment: This question is answered in about 658388456 answers alone here on SO. Maybe not such that you can copy the answer by copy&paste. But please note that you are expected to understand the tools you are using when asking a question here. So we expect that you are able to adapt a given solution to your specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?category$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?category/ / [L,R=301]
```

For versions of the apache http server >= 2.3.9 this version is even more precise:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?category$ / [END,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?category/ / [END,R=301]
```

Obviously for this to work the rewrite engine has to be loaded inside your http server and you have to enable the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Would this work too?                                                                                  RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/$ http://your-domain.com/

Comment: Sure comes out the same, except that I would _not_ code the host name in a rewriting rule, since that makes code non portable for no reason at all... _Except_ obviously if you want to redirect to a _different_ host name, but you did not state that in your question.

Comment: Oh, and... `^/category/$` differs a little from the patterns I used. So be careful there... There is a reason why I used _two_ rules...

Comment: I just want to redirect all category and all pages only on that category to the home page. I will try your code first and see what happens. Will let you know. Sorry new to all this.

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHAMP. YOU ROCK! Now if anyone googles it, they can find this.

Comment: Nvm, to that question, it just took a while for the redirect to happen on 2nd domain. What if I want that category and all pages on it to direct to specific page? RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?category$ /pagename [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?category/ /pagename [L,R=301]